# Laravel php unit testing takes long in Windows Docker

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, docker

I am working on Laravel with docker.

If I run php unit test in mac os, it takes few seconds.

However on windows 10, it takes few mins.

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a non-Linux OS, Docker has to virtualise your file system, and this requires a certain amount of time per file. For programs that are compiled into one executable, this is less of a problem at runtime (but clearly with its own compilation-time implications), but for scripting languages like PHP this can mean that every request runs super slowly, since every file that is used has to be 'translated' **every time it is read**. This is also a problem on Docker for Mac (so you're actually experiencing problems there, too, but less so, since at least it's a Linux system under the hood.) Linux is, I believe, completely virtualised on Windows which is going to add even more time.

This Reddit discusses the problem to an extent:

https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/7xvlye/docker_for_macwindows_performances_vs_linux/

With this being particularly interesting (**I have not tried it myself**):

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly

There is also a good community-created solution which **we have used to solve our Docker for Mac problem**. I don't see why their Windows options wouldn't work similarly well in your case. You can find it here:

https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/wiki/docker-sync-on-Windows

It basically sets up an intermediate service that copies all the files over into an intermediate volume (that uses the 'correct' filesystem) only when the file is updated, therefore speeding up run speed immensely.

I know it looks like quite an intimidating process, but this problem is fundamental, so you're going to have to do a certain amount of work to fix things!

FWIW I had that working on Docker 4 Mac, but it added a layer of complexity to our dev process that I found annoying, so in the end I've got myself a Linux box for work. To be honest, installing Linux as dual boot on my Windows machine (which has been my at-home solution) was probably easier than tweaking Docker 4 Mac to my satisfaction, so you might want to consider that. I have used this page twice:

https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

And it's worked fine each time. One caveat - it suggests a low amount of disk for your root (/) volume, but Docker gets mounted on root so give it around 100G (not the 10-20G that page recommends.)